# Replace in Regex Match

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net, replace

I'm using the following VB.net Code to find phone numbers in HTML and make them "clickable":

```
 Regex.Replace(pDisp.Document.Body.innerHTML, "([0-9+ ]{3,6}[\s]{1,1}[0123456789 \-/]{4,15})", "<a href=http://DIAL/$1>$1</a>")
```

There appears an issue if the numbers contain white spaces, for example:

```
089 12233 455
```

This will be replaced with:

```
<a href=http://DIAL/089 12233 455>089 12233 455</a>
```

Is there a way to get

```
<a href=http://DIAL/08912233455>089 12233 455</a>
```

instead?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `<a href=http://DIAL/$1>$1</a>`, use:

```
<a href=http://DIAL/$1>$0</a>
```

so that the output text is the whole capture, which will include the original formatting.

Comment: I'm not suggesting you change the part within the href (because your OP looked like that was working). I'm only suggesting changing the text between the `<a>` and `</a>` tags.

Comment: Okay, thanks... Unfortunately this is not working... It would be more important to the change the href itself...

Comment: Hmm.. think I've misinterpretted your question - I think Ahmad's MatchEvaluator looks a better option.

Answer (score 1):

You can reach a solution using the [`Regex.Replace` overload that accepts a `MatchEvaluator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht1sxswy.aspx).

Example:

```
Dim pattern = "([0-9+ ]{3,6}[\s]{1,1}[0123456789 \-/]{4,15})"
Dim inputs As String() = { "089 12233 455", "0711 123 00 376", "0711 5600920", "0711 62009211", "0711 620092 11", "+49 711 123 00 376", "0049 711 5600920" }

For Each input In inputs
    Console.WriteLine(input)
    Dim result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern,
        Function(m) "<a href=http://DIAL/" & m.Value.Replace(" ", "") & ">" & m.Value & "</a>")
    Console.WriteLine("Result: {0}", result)
    Console.WriteLine()
Next
```

The lambda uses the `Match` result and we build the link while replacing spaces with empty strings, and keeping the original value unaltered for the link text. You could make it more readable using `String.Format` if the concatenation looks unreadable. If the `href` needs to strip the leading plus sign, you could chain another `String.Replace` or perform another regex replace on `[+ ]` to remove spaces and plus signs.

I also think you can shorten your original regex to `"[0-9+ ]{3,6}\s[0-9 -]{4,15}"`. Compared to your original pattern, the `[\s]{1,1}` has been shortened, and the `[0123456789 \-/]` uses a 0-9 range as you've done earlier. As long as the dash is placed either at the beginning or end of the character class, it doesn't need to be escaped. Lastly, I removed the `/` since I saw no examples with a forward slash.

Answer (score 0):

You could break your capture groups up. Then, in your replace, do something like this:

```
"<a href=http://DIAL/$1$2$3>$1 $2 $3</a>"
```

Comment: That would also make every match space-separated for the output (as long as that's acceptable).

Comment: I have already tried this. My problem is, that there can be many different formats:
+49 89 123456 789
089 123 456 789
089 123456789

Comment: Will the # of digits always be the same?
--edit - I guess not, since you gave examples with different numbers of digits :)

Comment: No... These are some real-world examples:

Comment: 0711 123 00 376, 0711 5600920, 0711 62009211, 0711 620092 11, +49 711 123 00 376, 0049 711 5600920